# PHP coding standards

Tags: php, coding-style

I've been looking for some guidelines on how to layout PHP code. I've found some good references, such as the following:

http://www.dagbladet.no/development/phpcodingstandard/

and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214/whats-a-good-standard-code-layout-for-a-php-application) on SO.

However, none of that quite gets to what I'm specifically wondering about, which is the integration of HTML and PHP. For example:

1. Is it OK to have a PHP file that starts out with HTML tags and only has PHP inserted where needed? Or should you just have one section of PHP code that contains everything?
2. If you have a chunk of PHP code in the middle of which is a set of `echo`'s that just output a fixed bit of HTML, is it better to break out of PHP and just put in the HTML directly?
3. Should functions all be defined in dedicated PHP files, or is it OK to define a bunch of functions at the top of a file and call them later on in that same file?

There are probably other questions I'd like to ask, but really I'm looking for someone to point me at some kind of resource online that offers guidance on the general idea of how HTML and PHP should be combined together.

Comment: The first link: *"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"*

Comment: The second link is the deleted question *"What's a good standard code layout for a PHP application?"*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's really not a single, common standard for these things. Most languages are more restrictive than PHP in this sense.

In the later years, a lot of so-called frameworks have emerged, and amongst other things they define a set of rules for everything from naming over where to place files and to which style your code should follow. There are several frameworks around, so you can't really pick one and call it the standard. However, most frameworks have a subset of commonality. For example, most follows some variant of the [PEAR Coding Standards](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php).

Answer (score 8):

Combining programming code and output data (including HTML) is IMHO a very bad idea. Most of the PHP gurus I know use a template engine such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) to help keep the two things separate.

Answer (score 4):

I usually try and follow the standards that are set by the language's core libraries.... oh wait.

Seriously through - you should try and follow the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) in any web application as it is pretty much standard practice regardless of language. In PHP this can be achieved in a quick-and-dirty way by treating `index.php` as your controller and separating data logic and presentation by file. This small step will at least let you move your code to a full featured framework when and if you choose.

Answer (score 3):

Use a template engine when you can. If you haven't learned one, or don't want the overhead (which is minimal), use practices that cause you to have quick-and-dirty templating:

- Functions that do not display anything have no place in a file that does display something.
- Print variables, not HTML. Whenever outputting HTML, break out of the PHP and write HTML with print statements to handle any small details that are needed (actions for forms, IDs for controls, etc.).
- Remember, when you include a file that breaks out of the PHP to print content, that will be treated the same as if you do it in the main file. So you can create simple templates that just included PHP files, and those files will print variables in the right places. Your index.php (or whatever) does all the real work, but all the display is done by the secondary "template".

Many PHP tutorials intermix logic and display code. It took me years to break the bad habits that encouraged in me. In my experience you can't separate things too much in PHP, and entropy will pull you towards intermixed code if you don't fight it.

Comment: I regard php as a template engine in itself... you can survive just fine without adding smarty etc to the mix. The only time I'd look into something like that would be if I was getting 3rd parties to edit templates online etc, and I wanted to restrict what they can do.

Answer (score 2):

Coding standards should be more than how to layout your syntax, but sadly that's what they tend to be in PHP.

FWIW, [phc](http://phpcompiler.org) will pretty print your code in the Zend style.