# Where can I find some documentation on the best scripting/indent style?

Tags: php, javascript

Where can I find some documentation on the best scripting/indent style? I have found lots of confusing documentation but no clear answers.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you intend for `doAnotherAmazingThing();` to be indented another time?

Comment: Scripting style standards exist so that ___everyone___ in a team of developers can find a style easy to read, not just one individual at the expense of everybody else. The __best__ is the one that is defined for your team that everyone in the team uses

Comment: @Asaph Quit hatin' on his script style, man :p

Comment: @Zenith that wasn't hatin', was it?

Comment: If you want to see how other people do it then check out this guide by  developers at AirBnb: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

Comment: @Asaph Haha I was kidding! It tied in quite nicely with the OP's first sentence

Comment: There is no "best" indentation style. Use the one that works best for your situation. If you are a part of a team, the one that works is the one that has been adopted by the team. For your own code, use what makes you feel good. However, for reference, the most common styles are described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style).

Comment: I work alone, and have nobody to answer to with regards to my coding style. I appreciate any constructive comments you have, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want, take a look here:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html

or search for coding style standards. If you work alone then it might not even matter, but if you work in a team, you all should adapt a similar coding standard.

Comment: I do work alone, and welcome any positive feedback from more experienced coders. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the  zend standard since that was the first one i learn and i like it and i think coding styles is just a personal preference take a look at this, it might help you

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html

also check out a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/307151/1287608

Answer (score 0):

Styling can be subjective, but I use tools like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) and [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) to test code quality.

Comment: I'm assuming you were talking about JavaScript. My apologies if that's not the case.

Comment: Yeah, that could be PHP based on the tags also. It'll be gone in a bit.